# MySQLi GROUP BY Column1 (and Column2 when Column1 = X)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I want to do a MySQL Group By with 1 column and then group by a 2nd if the 1st is Like something.

I've never seen anything like this so I'm struggling to find how to do it.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `UsageDailyUnusedSlots` 
WHERE Date = '$SQLDate' AND (RotaType LIKE '%Aural%' OR RotaType LIKE 
'%Colonoscopy%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Cystoscopy%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Derm%' OR 
RotaType LIKE 'ENT -%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Gastroscopy%' OR RotaType LIKE 
'%Gastroenterology%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Minor Surg%' OR(RotaType LIKE 
'%MRI%' AND (SlotType Like '%York or LTHT MRI%' OR SlotType LIKE '%ENT 
MRI%')) OR RotaType LIKE '%Ophthalmology%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Sigmoid%' OR 
RotaType LIKE '%Skinfinity%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Prostate%' OR RotaType LIKE 
'%Urology%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Vasectomy%')
GROUP BY RotaType, SlotType 
ORDER BY RotaType";
```

Here is my SQL query but I only want to GROUP BY SlotType if RotaType is LIKE Gastroscopy

Cheers

Comment: perhaps a Union?

Answer (score 0):

> (RotaType LIKE '%Aural%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Colonoscopy%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Cystoscopy%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Derm%' OR RotaType LIKE 'ENT -%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Gastroscopy%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Gastroenterology%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Minor Surg%' OR(RotaType LIKE '%MRI%' AND (SlotType Like '%York or LTHT MRI%' OR SlotType LIKE '%ENT MRI%')) OR RotaType LIKE '%Ophthalmology%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Sigmoid%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Skinfinity%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Prostate%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Urology%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Vasectomy%')

Are combined boolean conditions

```
"SELECT * FROM `UsageDailyUnusedSlots` 
WHERE Date = '$SQLDate' AND (RotaType LIKE '%Aural%' OR RotaType LIKE
'%Colonoscopy%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Cystoscopy%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Derm%' OR 
RotaType LIKE 'ENT -%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Gastroscopy%' OR RotaType LIKE 
'%Gastroenterology%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Minor Surg%' OR(RotaType LIKE 
'%MRI%' AND (SlotType Like '%York or LTHT MRI%' OR SlotType LIKE '%ENT 
MRI%')) OR RotaType LIKE '%Ophthalmology%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Sigmoid%' OR 
RotaType LIKE '%Skinfinity%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Prostate%' OR RotaType LIKE 
'%Urology%' OR RotaType LIKE '%Vasectomy%')
GROUP BY CASE 
WHEN RotaType LIKE '%Gastroscopy%' THEN SlotType
ELSE RotaType END
ORDER BY RotaType";
```

Comment: but I need the rest of those conditions in my Query

Comment: ...and the rest of those rota types have different slot types, but I only need to split by SlotType where rota type is Endoscopy